# Prove that this function space is a basis.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=[0,1]^{[0,1]}$, the set of all functions $f : [0,1] \to [0,1]$. Given a subset $A \subseteq [0,1]$, let $U(A) = \{f \in X : f(x) = 0 \forall x \in A\}$.

Show that $\mathcal{B} := \{U(A) : A\subseteq [0,1]\}$ is a basis for a topology on $X$.

I’m having difficulty understanding what this question is asking. The set $X$ consists of functions.

I know that to show that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis we need to show that for for every $x \in X$ there is at least one basis element that contains it (is every element of $x$ in this sense a function?  ) And we need to show that for every two elements of $\mathcal{B}$ there exists an element of $\mathcal{B}$ that is a subset to their intersection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A_1 $ and $A_2$ are subsets of $[0,1]$ then $$UA_1 \cap UA_2=\{f: f(x) =0 \forall x \in A_1 \text {and} f(x) =0 \forall x \in A_2\}$$ $$= \{f: f(x) =0 \forall x \in A_1\cup A_2\}=U(A_1 \cup A_2).$$ Hence the family $(UA)_{A \subset [0,1]}$ is a basis for some topology.

Comment: Thanks. How do we show that for every element of the function space there is a basis element that contains it

Comment: @AlexM. When they define $UA$ for $A \subset [0,1]$ they are including the case when $A$ is empty. That makes the union of all $UA$'s equal to $X$.

Comment: Let’s say one of the functions is a constant maps [0,1] to 1 ie constant.  Which basis element contains it ?

Comment: It belongs to $U\emptyset$. @AlexM.

Comment: So the empty set contains the constant functions for example?

Comment: Ok great.  Thanks

Comment: Why are we taking union of A1 and A2 for second line of proof rather than intersection?

Comment: A function vanishes on $A_1$ as well as $A_2$ iff it vanishes on $A_1 \cup A_2$. @AlexM.

Comment: I see that makes sense. Thank you.